# Resolving version conflict due to external transitive dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am getting below error -

```
servlet [jersey] in context with path [/GeneralService] threw exception
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri
```

I am getting this error after adding a new external dependency which has below dependencies in it's pom.xml file-

1. jersey-client - 2.25.1 which in turn depends on -
2. javax.ws.rs-api - 2.0.1

when I exclude javax.ws.rs-api - 2.0.1 from the dependency heirarchy, I don't get the above mentioned error but then this external dependency code doesn't work as it depending on this artifact.

My main application has below jersey related dependencies in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
   <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
   <version>1.18</version>
   <exclusions>...</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
   <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

So my main application depends on the jersey version 1.18 and external dependency depends on jersey version 2.0.1.
I am unable to figure out a way to resolve this so that it runs smoothly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Choose a different library. This one will not be compatible with your app. Trying to mix Jersey major versions is a not going to work. Any way you try to work it, you will run into problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a consistent version of jersey, preferably 2.x. So update all your dependencies to 2.x and then figure out step by step which changes you need to make in your own code to make that work.

There is no sensible way to use different versions of the same artifact simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks JF Meier. Let me try out upgrading version to 2.x jersey.

Answer (score 0):

The jersey version 1.18 use `java.ws.rs` version 1.1.1 as compile dependency. See:

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.18

Since you're talking about using jersey 2.25.1, I suggest to upgrade your pom to glassfish jersey 2.25:

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.25.1

like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the dependency to `java.ws.rs` will be 2.0.1.

As for `jersey-spring` artifact, it don't depends on `java.ws.rs`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in this case I will have to replace all the 3 jersey dependencies from my main application with jersey-client?

Comment: See my edit. I think that replacing two of the dependencies and keeping the jersey-spring should work.

Comment: Thanks again @JFPicard. Let me try this out. Will share the results.